# How apply auth restriction in JSPUI?

Tags: user-experience, dspace

How apply auth restriction in JSPUI? I was wanting in JSPUI apply when the user tries to access the feedback form, the dspace require authentication, but I could not understand how the pages that require authentication as in 'mydspace' works in JSPUI.

It is possible for jsp pages? or need change java class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authentication requirement is set up in web.xml ([link to 5.x version](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-5_x/dspace-jspui/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml)). It may be enough to add another filter-mapping clause for the feedback URL, eg

```
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>registered-only</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/feedback</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

But I haven't tried it! This may not work.